# how to check if array contain positive value in php

Tags: php, arrays

i have searched through the Internet with no luck. I have array of integers and i want to check if my array contain positive value.

**my array**

```
$Myarray = {1,3,7,-6,-9,-23,-8};
```

i tried to use `in_array()  function` with no luck;

any help  please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple `foreach` ?

```
foreach($Myarray as $v)
{
    if($v>0)
    {
        echo "Array contains a +ve value";
        break;
    }
}
```

Another way would be this..

```
$Myarray = array(-1,-3,-7,-6,-9,-23,-8);
rsort($Myarray);
echo ($Myarray[0] > 0) ? "Array contains +ve value" : "Array does not contain +ve value";
```

Comment: Why do you sort your array? If you really want to use a sort function, it better to sort by DESC order and then looking for the ***first element***. But here you sort the array whose complexity is `O(n*ln(n))` and then you make a linear loop. It's makes no sense

Comment: Sorting the array takes a lot more time than just looping through it once.

Comment: The reason for the sort is .. Say if the array has 1000 elements and the first 999 elements are negative , and the last element is the positive one , so using a `foreach` will loop through all the elements right or maybe I am wrong ? **Rolled it back**

Comment: 'If the array has 1000 elements and the first 999 elements are negative', your sort function will loop throught all theese elements too. The better sorting algorithm is `O(nln(n))` in general and `O(n)` in the best case (if the array is already sorted). A simple loop is `O(n)` in general and `O(1)` in the best case (if you find the positive element at the first position). ***Make your choice!***

Comment: @Gwenc37, So sorting an array by descending order and then checking for the first element is better or using a `foreach` to loop through all is better ?.. which one you suggest ?

Comment: I depends. If you don't need a sorted array, it's better to do a single loop. But if you use this kind of verification on an array very often, it could be better to sort it one time and then you will be sure that you will have a constant complexity. If you make `k` verification on the same array, the question is : is `k*O(n)` better than `O(n*ln(n))`?. Same think if you think you will need to sort you array letter, it's a good solution to sort it at first before doing this verification.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an array reduction for that:

```
$result = array_reduce($Myarray, function ($result, $num) { return $result || $num > 0; });
if ($result) {
    echo "Yes, there's at least one positive number in there.";
}
```

You'd want another solution which doesn't iterate the whole array if your array is very large, but for small arrays this does just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Simple one liner:

```
if (count(array_filter([-23], function($v){ return ($v >= 1); }))) echo "has positive values\n";
```

In function form:

```
function array_positive($arr) {
   return (bool) count(array_filter($arr, function($v){ return ($v >= 1); }));
}

php > var_dump(array_positive([-23]));
bool(false)
php > var_dump(array_positive([-23, 12]));
bool(true)
```

Like the other examples above it works by looping through the array. The difference is that my example creates a new array containing only the positive values (this is the return value from array_filter), get the size of the new array and then converts that to a boolean value.

You could easily change it to a function that returns only the positive values from an array:

```
function array_positive_values($arr) {
    return array_filter($arr, function($v){ return ($v >= 1); });
}
```

Also note that neither of these validate that the values are actually numbers.